# How to remove white spaces at the end of every value between delimiter in a file?

Tags: bash, shell, sed

I have pipe delimited file that looks like this:

```
col1|col2|col3|col4
a   |b  | some value | hello world     
a   |b  | some value | hello world     
a   |b  | some value | hello world     
a   |b  | some value | hello world
```

The values in each column, including the last, have trailing white spaces. How do I remove trailing white spaces using `sed` so that my output looks like this?

```
col1|col2|col3|col4
a|b|some value|hello world
a|b|some value|hello world
a|b|some value|hello world
a|b|some value|hello world
```

This is what I have tried which removes spaces between the delimiters, but not at the end of last column:

```
sed -i -e "s/\s*|/|/g" somefile.txt
```

Answer (score 2):

You may use this `sed`:

```bash
sed -E 's/[[:blank:]]*(\|)[[:blank:]]*|[[:blank:]]+$/\1/g' file

col1|col2|col3|col4
a|b|some value|hello world
a|b|some value|hello world
a|b|some value|hello world
a|b|some value|hello world
```

Here:

- `[[:blank:]]+(\|)[[:blank:]]*`: Match whitespaces before and after `|`
- `|`: OR
- `[[:blank:]]+$`: Match whitespaces before end

---

Alternative solution in `awk`:

```bash
awk -F ' *\\| *' -v OFS='|' '{sub(/ +$/, "", $NF)} 1' file
```

Comment: Why not `sed -E 's/[[:blank:]]*(\||$)[[:blank:]]*/\1/g'` ?

Comment: Sure that will do it in single `s` or even `sed -E 's/[[:blank:]]+(\|)[[:blank:]]*|[[:blank:]]+$/\1/g' file`

Answer (score 1):

You can use this `sed`command:

```
sed 's/[[:blank:]]*$//; s/[[:blank:]]*|[[:blank:]]*/|/g' file
```

If you want to remove leading blanks as well, then just add `s/^[[:blank:]]*//` to the `sed` expression above.

Answer (score 0):

***1st solution:*** Here is one more `awk` variant, written and tested with your shown samples; written and tested in GNU `awk`.

```
awk -F'[[:space:]]*\\|[[:space:]]*' -v OFS="|" '
{
  sub(/[[:space:]]+$/,"")
  $1=$1
}
1
'  Input_file
```

---

---

***2nd solution:*** Making field separator in `awk` and using `match` function of GNU `awk` please try following.

```bash
awk -F '[[:space:]]*\\|[[:space:]]*' -v OFS='|' '
($1=$1) && match($0,/[[:space:]]+$/){
  print substr($0,1,RSTART-1)
}
'  Input_file
```

Answer (score 0):

With `perl`:

```bash
perl -lpe 's/\s+(?=\||$)|\|\K\s+//g'

perl -F'\|' -lane 'print join "|", map {s/^\s+|\s+$//gr} @F'

perl -F'\s*\|\s*' -lane '$F[-1]=~s/\s+$//; print join "|", @F'
```

Use `perl -i` for inplace editing.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -E 's/^\s+|\s*(\|)\s*|\s+$/\1/g' file
```

Use alternation (`|`) in order to remove spaces before the first field, at either end of fields and at the end of a record.

N.B. The middle alternation uses the `*` quantifier instead of the `+` because it is doing double duty, removing white space from either side of a field delimiter. However this in turn means every field delimiter will by substituted. If each occurrence of white space were done separately, the substitution command would have to be repeated to take care of those substitutions missed in the first round i.e. the regexp engine does not backtrack within a global (`g` flag) context.